# Is it possible to create a light-weight number wrapper type in TypeScript, similar to Color struct in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, typescript, struct

First of all, I apologize for not expressing myself concisely/clearly - sadly I do not know exact concepts that are applicable to my problem. Now, to the case...

In C#/.NET there is a Color struct. This struct essentially has one int32 field which represents color and provides some convenience methods for working with it. Thanks to how structs work in .NET, working with an array of Color would be as efficient (in terms of time and memory) as working with an array of int32 on one hand, and provide type-safety on another hand, since for example, compiler would not allow to assign arbitrary int32 anywhere where color is expected.

In TypeScript, I could achieve type safety, by wrapping number inside an object, but this will create a runtime overhead of using an object instead of number.

What I am looking for is essentially a way to tell TypeScript compiler "this type is number internally, but it is a totally separate type for your concerns (unless I cast it explicitly of course)". Is there any way to do that in TypeScript?

Comment: You're totally describing an enum...

Comment: Maybe `const enum` is what you are looking for? [have a look](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) - almost at the bottom of that page

Comment: You had to pick *that* example didn't you? [`Color` is surprisingly complex and stateful, not just an `Int32`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Color.cs,1342)

Comment: And the WPF one isn't [any simpler](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Media/Color.cs,1153) :-)

Comment: @zaitsman, nilsK, enums do seem like a close match. I have one concern though (perhaps more philosophical). Does compiler assert that value of enum type can only have values specified in the enum? In particular, for control flow analysis perhaps? Because in case of color it can be any int32 value.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I was hoping no one will notice :) anyway for my purpose int32 sufficient :)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, besides, even with 4 fields, struct will be still packed in the array (hence fields can be accessed by offset, not indirection). That actually gave me a new idea - would it be possible (almost sure it wouldn't, but still) to 'pack' a type into an array in TypeScript. Thinking more about it, it might actually be a good feature because I saw programmers implement that kind of 'packing' more than once (and the situations seemed justified)

Comment: @ironic well you're talking about typescript. Typescript is just a set of syntactic sugars that transpile down to real javascript. JS has no real support for what you're talking about (re: limiting the enum value), so yes you could shove any value to any argument. What that would mean for your code is what you want to write. Practically, if you want to have any value in a certain format, just use a class. You do not get the same compiler optimizations that you do in C# when you work in JS.